# How do i add functionality to my nav dots in my image slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Currently my nav dots do not have any functionality. How do i add that.
This is my code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import {Container,ButtonP, ButtonN,IMG, SliderContainer } from './sliderElements';
import './sliderEle.css';


import img1 from '../../images/slider1.png';
import img2 from '../../images/slider2.png';
import img3 from '../../images/slider3.png';
import img4 from '../../images/slider4.png';
import img5 from '../../images/slider5.png';


function Slider() {
  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0);
  const slideRef = useRef(null);
  
  const TOTAL_SLIDES = 4;
  const image = [
    {
      src : img1,
      title: "Welcome to Minter!",
      para: "Minter is the dApp for OKS holders. If you've never used Minter before, read through our quick introduction first."
    },
    {
      src : img2, 
      title: "What is Oikos?",
      para: "Oikos is a decentralised synthetic asset issuance protocol built on Binance Smart Chain. These synthetic assets (Synths) are created by staking the Oikos Network Token (OKS), and these Synths can be exchanged for each other directly with the Oikos smart contracts on Oikos.Exchange."
    },
    {
      src : img3, 
      title: "Why stake OKS?",
      para: "OKS stakers receive two kinds of rewards. Firstly, they receive OKS staking rewards, which are created through the inflationary monetary policy. Secondly, there’s Synth exchange rewards, which are generated by Synth trades on Oikos.Exchange."
    },
    {
      src : img4, title: "What do OKS stakers need to do?",
      para: "All Synths need to be backed by staked OKS at a Collateralisation Ratio of 750%. OKS stakers need to manage their own ratio to be above this figure, which they can do by burning Synths to increase their ratio or minting Synths to reduce it. If they do this, they can collect weekly rewards."
    },
    {
      src : img5, title: "What are the risks?",
      para: "All OKS stakers create a ‘debt’ when they stake. Their debt begins as the amount of oUSD they initially mint, and fluctuates according to gains or losses made by other Synth holders. Any time anyone holds a Synth that appreciates in value, that gain is distributed proportionally between all the staked OKS holders’ debts. A staker must pay off their debt before they can unlock their staked OKS."
    }
  ];
  

  const nextSlide = () => {
      if (currentSlide >= TOTAL_SLIDES) { 
        setCurrentSlide(0);
      } else {
        setCurrentSlide(currentSlide + 1);
      }
    };

  const prevSlide = () => {
    if (currentSlide === 0) {
      setCurrentSlide(TOTAL_SLIDES);
    } else {
      setCurrentSlide(currentSlide - 1);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    slideRef.current.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease-in-out";
    slideRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(-${currentSlide}00%)`; 
    
  }, [currentSlide]);

 

return (
  
  <Container>
  
  <SliderContainer ref={slideRef}>
  
  {image.map(image => (
    <div>
      <h1 className="title">{image.title}</h1>
      <p className="para">{image.para}</p>
      <IMG src={image.src} key={image} />
      
    </div>
  ))}
  </SliderContainer>
    
  <div class="dot-container">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(0)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
  </div>

  <div className="combuttons">
  <ButtonP onClick={prevSlide}>
    <span className="previous"><h2>PREVIOUS</h2></span></ButtonP>
    <div class="divider"/>  
      <ButtonN onClick={nextSlide}><span className="nextbut"><h2>NEXT</h2></span></ButtonN>
      </div>
</Container>
  );
}

export default Slider;
```

[image: This is how my page looks:]

The previous and next buttons are working fine. Its the dots that i am unable to add functionality to. Any help would be appreciated. Since i am using an array to display the images The list way to  nav dots doesn't work .I would also like the dots to show which slide i am currently on..how do i do that too. Pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following:

```html
<span class="dot" onClick={() => currentSlide(0)}></span>
<span class="dot" onClick={() => currentSlide(1)}></span>
<span class="dot" onClick={() => currentSlide(2)}></span>
<span class="dot" onClick={() => currentSlide(3)}></span>
<span class="dot" onClick={() => currentSlide(4)}></span>
```

Or wrap your span in a styled button.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this way:

```
<div class="dot-container">
  <span class="dot" onClick={() => setCurrentSlide(0)}></span>
  <span class="dot" onClick={() => setCurrentSlide(1)}></span>
  <span class="dot" onClick={() => setCurrentSlide(2)}></span>
  <span class="dot" onClick={() => setCurrentSlide(3)}></span>
  <span class="dot" onClick={() => setCurrentSlide(4)}></span>
</div>
```

But To avoid excessive repetition span tag I recommand to use this way;

Also if you use id for each image, its can be use insted of index (better way)

```
 <div class="dot-container">
  {image.map((s,index) => {
       return (
          <span className={index === currentSlide ? "dot red" : "dot white"} onClick={() => setCurrent(index)}></span>
       )
   })}
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the second part works.....The first one gave an error when we clicked on the dots.

Comment: I would also like the dots to show which slide i am currently on..how do i do that ??? @mehdi.

Comment: @chloe For the first part use setCurrentSlide, i made a mistake

Comment: Also for the second part create a p tag and inside that use ``` slide {index} ```

Comment: i didn't get you about the second part -@Mehdi

Comment: @Chloe I edited the second part of my code, look at it

Comment: noo..i wanted the dots to show which slide they are on...like if its on slide 2 the second nav dot should be different color

Comment: I got it. I edited my post again. try that. for this situation you should use conditional className

Comment: Its not working , Its not showing any color- @Mehdi

Comment: I edited it again; but you should add red or white or any colors class in your CSS styles

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a string that you're trying to give on your onClick ?
Instead of this:

```
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(0)"></span>
```

Maybe try this:

```
<span className="dot" onClick={() => setCurrentSlide(0)}></span>
```